# How to force XML to treat special chars as a plain text?

Tags: xml

Structure <!-- some text --> is a comment in XML, but I would like to put this text inside another tag and I don't want it to be treated as a comment, just as text (I need it in visual studio's class's comment), like this:

```
<summary>
   (...) that contains
   sections marked with <!--[section_name]--> at the beginning.
</summary>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CDATA or escape the characters using &gt; or &lt; for < and > respectively.

Comment: visual studio doesn't care about CDATA section in xml comment (just treats it as another tag), but &lt; and &gt; worked. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use code like this:

```
<xml>
  <![CDATA[

    <!-- comment treated as plain text -->

  ]]>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at CDATA-term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

```
<summary>
    <![CDATA[
    (...) that contains
    sections marked with <\!--[section_name]--> at the beginning.
    ]]>
</summary>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the contents of the element in a CDATA section. This tells the parser to treat the contents as literal.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the text inside a CDATA tag:

```
<summary>
<![CDATA[   (...) that contains
   sections marked with <!--[section_name]--> at the beginning.]]>
</summary>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either escape the characters...

```
<summary>Blah blah &lt;!-- not a comment --&gt; blah.</summary>
```

...or wrap them inside a PCDATA section:

```
<summary><![CDATA[Blah blah <!-- blah -->]]></summary>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is to use CDATA, but I strongly recommend escaping. If you use CDATA, you have to verify that your content does not contain "]]>", and somehow escape it if it does (unlikely in many cases, but if your program exists to insert XML in other XML, the risk goes up).

Also, *use a serializer* to generate your XML, because there are a lot of picky rules that almost everyone gets wrong (I've been writing XML for 12 years and don't trust myself to get them all right). The simplest approach is to build a DOM and then transform it into text.